# Hide or clear a PHP form on submit

Tags: php, forms, submit, hide, captcha

I have a php contact form which all works well with its validation etc, but I have one niggle with it. The original code which I have tweaked redirected the page to a new one with a thank you message on submission which I was unhappy with, so I've managed to get a thank you message to display on the original page, however the input form content still stays, i'd rather it didn't. Even better I'd like to be able to hide the form completely and replace it with a thank you.

I ought to mention that when completed it will be placed on a page with other items, so it is just the form that I'm after hiding, or clearing.

This is the code in the Header

```
<?php 
$your_email ='email@example.com';

session_start();
$errors = '';
$name = '';
$company = '';
$visitor_email = '';
$phone = '';
$user_message = '';

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

$name = $_POST['name'];
$company = $_POST['company'];
$visitor_email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$user_message = $_POST['message'];
///------------Do Validations-------------
if(empty($name)||empty($visitor_email))
{
    $errors .= "\n Name and Email are required fields. ";   
}
if(IsInjected($visitor_email))
{
    $errors .= "\n Bad email value!";
}
if(empty($_SESSION['6_letters_code'] ) ||
  strcasecmp($_SESSION['6_letters_code'], $_POST['6_letters_code']) != 0)
{
//Note: the captcha code is compared case insensitively.
//if you want case sensitive match, update the check above to
// strcmp()
    $errors .= "\n The captcha code does not match!";
}

if(empty($errors))
{
    //send the email
    $to = $your_email;
    $subject="New form submission";
    $from = $your_email;
    $ip = isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) ? $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] : '';

    $body = "A user  $name submitted the contact form:\n".
    "Name: $name\n".
    "Company: $company\n".

    "Email: $visitor_email \n".
    "Phone: $phone\n".

    "Message: \n ".
    "$user_message\n".
    "IP: $ip\n";    

    $headers = "From: $from \r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $visitor_email \r\n";

    mail($to, $subject, $body,$headers);

    //header('Location: #thanks');
    $myForm =  '< style="visibility: hidden;">';
    $thankyou = file_get_contents("thank-you.html"); 
}
}

// Function to validate against any email injection attempts
function IsInjected($str)
{
 $injections = array('(\n+)',
          '(\r+)',
          '(\t+)',
          '(%0A+)',
          '(%0D+)',
          '(%08+)',
          '(%09+)'
          );
  $inject = join('|', $injections);
  $inject = "/$inject/i";
if(preg_match($inject,$str))
{
return true;
}
else
{
return false;
}
}


?>
```

And this is the form itself minus a chunk of javascript validation which I didn't think was relevant to the question

```
<?php
if(!empty($errors)){
echo "<p class='err'>".nl2br($errors)."</p>";
}
?>
<div id="footer">
    <div class="twelve-column-wrapper">
        <div class="six-column-wrapper">
            <div class="six-column">
                <h3>Why not get in touch</h3>
            </div>
            <div id='contact_form_errorloc' class='err'></div>
            <form method="POST" name="contact_form" 
action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>">
                <div class="three-column">
                    <p>
                        <label for='name'>Name: </label>
                        <br>
                        <input type="text" name="name" value='<?php echo htmlentities($name) ?>'>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="three-column">
                    <p>
                        <label for='company'>Your Company: </label>
                        <input type="text" name="company" id="company" value='<?php echo htmlentities($company) ?>'/>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="three-column">
                    <p>
                        <label for='email'>Email: </label>
                        <br>
                        <input type="text" name="email" value='<?php echo htmlentities($visitor_email) ?>'>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="three-column">
                    <p>
                        <label for='phone'>Phone No. </label>
                        <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" value='<?php echo htmlentities($phone) ?>'/>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="six-column">
                    <p>
                        <label for='message'>Message:</label>
                        <br>
                        <textarea name="message" rows=8 cols=30><?php echo htmlentities($user_message) ?></textarea>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="three-column">
                    <p> <img src="captcha_code_file.php?rand=<?php echo rand(); ?>" id='captchaimg' ><br>
                        <label for='message'>Enter the code above here :</label>
                        <br>
                        <input id="6_letters_code" name="6_letters_code" type="text">
                        <br>
                        <small>Can't read the image? click <a href='javascript: refreshCaptcha();'>here</a> to refresh</small> </p>
                    <input id="submit"  type="submit" value="Submit" name='submit'>
                </div>
                <div class="six-column"> <?php echo $thankyou; ?> </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried a few methods I've found by searching but have fallen down mainly due to my basic knowledge of PHP.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
if(!empty($errors)){
echo "<p class='err'>".nl2br($errors)."</p>";
}
?>
<div id="footer">
    <div class="twelve-column-wrapper">
        <div class="six-column-wrapper">
            <div class="six-column">
                <h3>Why not get in touch</h3>
            </div>
            <div id='contact_form_errorloc' class='err'></div>
<?php
if(!isset($_POST['submit'])):
?>
            <form method="POST" name="contact_form" 
action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>">
                <div class="three-column">
                    <p>
                        <label for='name'>Name: </label>
                        <br>
                        <input type="text" name="name" value='<?php echo htmlentities($name) ?>'>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="three-column">
                    <p>
                        <label for='company'>Your Company: </label>
                        <input type="text" name="company" id="company" value='<?php echo htmlentities($company) ?>'/>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="three-column">
                    <p>
                        <label for='email'>Email: </label>
                        <br>
                        <input type="text" name="email" value='<?php echo htmlentities($visitor_email) ?>'>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="three-column">
                    <p>
                        <label for='phone'>Phone No. </label>
                        <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" value='<?php echo htmlentities($phone) ?>'/>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="six-column">
                    <p>
                        <label for='message'>Message:</label>
                        <br>
                        <textarea name="message" rows=8 cols=30><?php echo htmlentities($user_message) ?></textarea>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="three-column">
                    <p> <img src="captcha_code_file.php?rand=<?php echo rand(); ?>" id='captchaimg' ><br>
                        <label for='message'>Enter the code above here :</label>
                        <br>
                        <input id="6_letters_code" name="6_letters_code" type="text">
                        <br>
                        <small>Can't read the image? click <a href='javascript: refreshCaptcha();'>here</a> to refresh</small> </p>
                    <input id="submit"  type="submit" value="Submit" name='submit'>
                </div>

            </form>
<?php
endif;
?>
            <div class="six-column"> <?php echo $thankyou; ?> </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

That will hide the form. But that won't prevent you to be spammed. If you don't want to be spammed to have to track IPs and before submitting the email check that the IP didn't already send an email let's say in the last 30 seconds, for instance.

Comment: That seems to work a treat. Thank you. I'm not actually too bothered about tracking IP addresses. This part came with the code I used for the captcha. I left it for novelty value really and because There didn't seem to be a need to remove it.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(empty($_POST)){
//You form goes here;
}
else{
echo $thankyou;
}
```

Also you can have something like:

```
if(empty($thankyou)){
//You form goes here;
}
else{
echo $thankyou;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You better create separate action file and for display thanks message use:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['msg'])){
echo $_SESSION['msg'];
}
else{
//display from here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger this function **onsubmit** or **onclick** event on form

```
 <script>
    function hideform()
    {
    document.forms['contact_form'].style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery to clear the form div on a successful submission.

```
$('#myform').submit(function(){
    $('#formcontainer').empty;
});
```

Where myform and form container are the ids of your form and the div containing your form